# Retina Display Issue

Tags: css, photoshop, retina-display

I'm trying to save an image from Photoshop to be used in a web page and it is displaying at twice the size on my web page than it is in photoshop. It also appears a tad blurry as if it has been scaled up 200%.

The image is 600px x 165px, and the CSS for the image is as follows:

```
display: block;
width: 600px;
height: 165px;
background: transparent url(logo.png) left top no-repeat;
text-indent: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Why is it displaying at twice the size in Chrome as it is in Photoshop? How do I get Chrome to display it at the correct size?

Answer (score 0):

This may be super obvious, but is your browser zoomed in?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Height and Width properties - This should set it to the size that it is set to in Photoshop

```
display: block;
background: transparent url(logo.png) left top no-repeat;
text-indent: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: Turns out you need to add a background-size specification. Setting this to 300px 83px made it show up correctly on my retina display.